# Update Array in Parallel?

Tags: python, list, multiprocessing

Assuming that I have a python list:

```
def func(arr, i):
    arr[i] = arr[i] + ' hello!'

xyz = ['a','b','c','d','e']

for i in range(len(xyz)):
     func(xyz, i)

for i in xyz:
     print i
```

and end up

```
a hello!
b hello!
c hello!
d hello!
e hello!
```

How do update the elements of the list in parallel using muticore since my list is very large?

I've searched all over and I can't seem to find the answer.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: Hi Haranadh, the expected output is an updated list: `a hello!
b hello!
c hello!
d hello!
e hello!` but I want to do it in parallel since the size of list could contain thousands of elements

Comment: You can look into using a [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers)

Comment: Why do you think updating each element in parallel would be more efficient ? Leaving that for python to decide would be better.

Comment: Hi Amr, I tried implemented a simple loop and taking too long. Python doesn't seem to be maximizing my CPUs. In theory, the process should be parallel-able since the updating one element of is not affected by the previous update.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @roganjosh's suggestion, I was able to find an answer:

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool

arr = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']

def edit_array(i):
    return arr[i] + ' hello!'

if __name__=='__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    list_start_vals = range(len(arr))
    array_2D = pool.map(edit_array, list_start_vals)
    pool.close()
    print array_2D
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one, relatively simple, way to do it using the `multiprocessing` module:

```
import functools
import multiprocessing

def func(arr, i):
    arr[i] = arr[i] + ' hello!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()  # Create a manager to handle shared object(s).
    xyz = manager.list(['a','b','c','d','e'])  # Create a proxy for the shared list object.

    p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)  # Create a pool of worker processes.

    # Create a single arg function with the first positional argument (arr) supplied.
    # (This is necessary because Pool.map() only works with functions of one argument.)
    mono_arg_func = functools.partial(func, xyz)

    p.map(mono_arg_func, range(len(xyz)))  # Run func in parallel until finished

    for i in xyz:
         print(i)
```

Output:

```
a hello!
b hello!
c hello!
d hello!
e hello!
```

Note this is **not** going to very fast if the list is huge because sharing access to large objects requires a lot of overhead between separate tasks (which run in different memory spaces).

A better approach would use a `multiprocessing.Queue` which is implemented "using a pipe and a few locks/semaphores" according to the documentation (as opposed to a shared list object whose entire contents will have to be pickled and unpickled multiple times).

Answer (score -1):

Getting from the question that you are wanting to replace the current value of an item in the list with the new value:

```
for position, value in enumerate(xyz):
    xyz[position] = '%s hello!' % value
```

Gives: ['a hello!', 'b hello!', 'c hello!', 'd hello!', 'e hello!']

Comment: Hello Martin, thanks for your reply. But how do i do it in parallel?

Comment: Use either multithreading or multiprocessing to distribute the work as roganjosh suggests in the comments above